# Excel. Weeknum function. #VALUE! error. Calendar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Value error]

Dear person. As you can see in the picture there is a #VALUE! error when it tries to show some weeknumbers.

Referring to the picture:

Nr. 1. I'm trying to figure out how to show the weeknumbers that have datenumbers in that week

Nr. 2. I'm trying to figure out how to show a blank cell for the rows with no datenumbers in that week

The workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed6dt022i0yz6py/Calendar.xlsx?dl=0

Help!:)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you want your week numbers to be based on weeks from Monday to Sunday? I was going to give an answer, but when I tested it noticed that April 1st would come out with a week number of 14, when you probably want it to be 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the one you want based on weeks from Monday to Sunday

```
=IFERROR(WEEKNUM(AGGREGATE(15,0,C17:I17,1),2),"")
```

I have chosen to use Aggregate because it will error out if there are no numbers in the range, so IFERROR will give a blank. You could just use MIN or MAX instead and test for the result being zero. You could also use LOOKUP or HLOOKUP. This might be the shortest way

```
=IFERROR(WEEKNUM(LOOKUP(99999,C17:I17),2),"")
```

The week starting with December 31st ('week 53') is really week 1 of 2019 so you could add a separate condition for this.

[image]

To fix the 'week 53' issue, I can't do any better than this rather long formula at present

```
=IF(COUNT(C17:I17)=0,"",IF(AND(MONTH(LOOKUP(9E+99,C17:I17))=12,C17<>"",I17=""),1,WEEKNUM(LOOKUP(9E+99,C17:I17),2)))
```

which says 'if it is the last week of December and at least one of the days in that week is empty, then the week is week one of the following year'.

This could be further modified to deal with an ISO year where week 1 is the first week containing a Thursday.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom Sharpe! Cool how LOOKUP and WEEKNUM combined works, Sharp indeed! I see  you referring to "99999", which means I'd have to change the formula when 13-10-2173 strikes, haha. I'll go with the first formula. And yes you are correct, monday is the first day of the week we count (Amsterdam)! I have tried a couple of things to fix weeknr. #53, but I seem to be running into a wall. Do you have any clues?

Comment: You're very welcome. Yes, that's funny, but strictly speaking it may be better to use something like 9E99 as a value which goes far into the future. Week 53 isn't necessarily incorrect! Here's an example of an iso year that starts with week 53...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_starting_on_Friday (but using the system where week 1 is the first week with a Thursday in it). Will think about it a bit more.

Comment: So the logic would be: If this is month 12 and Monday in this row is not blank but Sunday in this row is blank, then this week is week 1 of the following year.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and work on the the 'week 53' issue, I'll check what I can do from here mr. Sharp!:)